# Set float width and precision with variables

Tags: c, printf, width, precision

I am attempting to print floating point numbers with a user changeable width and precision. The problem I am having is that only the precision field is being read, width is being completely ignored.

```
int width = 4; int precision = 12;
printf("%*.*lf ", width , precision, value);

605.32364879299 5980.79287087619 802.32966093936
5839.78856776635 5355.77379680776 6602.20148319956
```

There is supposed to be a padding of spaces insuring that the decimals line up but it is as if the width variable is not even being read.

Comment: "width" is the _minimum_ text width of the entire text.  "6602.20148319956" has 17 characters, that is more than 4, so 17 characters are printed.

Comment: With 12 decimal places, a width of 4 is pretty much like saying "I don't care how wide the output is".  You'd need to specify a width of at least 17 to see any benefit for the sample data.  Read the specification of (POSIX) [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) again.

Answer (score 1):

> width is being completely ignored.

Certainly a mis-understanding of the *field width*.  It is a *minimum* count of characters to print including the sign, digits, decimal point, etc.

> An optional minimum *field width*. If the converted value has fewer characters than the field width, it is padded with spaces ... C11dr §7.21.6.1 4

```
int width = 4; int precision = 12;
double value =  605.32364879299;
printf("%*.*lf\n", width , precision, value);
width = 21;
printf("%*.*lf\n", width , precision, value);
/*
123456789012345678901 */
```

Output

```
605.323648792990       // Minimum width =  4, 16 characters in numeric text
     605.323648792990  // Minimum width = 21, 5 spaces + 16 characters in numeric text
```